# Find location of person with SPARQL in Java

Tags: java, semantic-web, sparql, ontology

I get an ontology from: http://webmind.dico.unimi.it/care/locont-2.0.owl. It contains location, person, activity, etc.

I want to find the location of person by SPARQL querying in Java.
The result of this query should be something like this:

```
("Ali" is located in "Kitchen")
```

Could someone help me with this query?

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, you'll need something like SELECT { "Ali" ?p ?o }. Then you'll have to restrict ?p to relationships that concern location. 
Here is a link to some [examples](http://wiki.musicontology.com/index.php/SPARQL_Examples); I hope you will find it useful.